# Chevy Silverado 1991 /w no reverse

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission

I have a Chevy Silverado 1991 with a 454 engine (6.4 liter) and has a 4l80e transmission. The last couple months shifting in reverse was a problem. You could hear the normal sound of it shifting but driving in reverse was choppy. Now there is no reverse at all. I was hoping to fix it myself but don’t know what needs to be fixed. I’ve look everywhere but there’s multiple opinions but I thought I would ask. Some people say it’s the reverse band some say it’s the sun cover (not sure if that’s what it’s actually called.) anyways any insight would be helpful thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you have your forward gears, your sun shell is not at issue. I don't think the sun shell is an issue in the 4L80e like it is in the 4L60e. Your problem would most likely be the reverse band or the solenoid for the reverse band. I'm no expert, so hopefully someone with a little more expertise than I have will give you more qualified information.

Comment: Google has some answers...https://www.google.com/search?q=4l80e+no+reverse&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS771US771&oq=4l80e+no+reverse&aqs=chrome..69i57.5287j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8